# Which one has better performance, data types .NET or alias name data types C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Hi to all first of all i am sorry because my first language is not english I want understand which one has better performance  C# data types or .net data types i try to understand by below code i test this code both with x86 and x64 platform.(**I emphasize please Complete reading this post to end  and If in doubt do not give the wrong answer and please Answer me with a document** )

```
StopWatch SW=new StopWatch();
   SW.Start();
   for (Int32 i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
   {
       for (Int32 j = 0; j < 999; j++)
       {
           Int32 a = 37;
           Int32 b = 37;
           Double c = Math.Pow(a, b);
           String d = "abcde";
           String e = "abcde";
           String f = d + e;
       }
```

second code

```
Stopwatch SW = new Stopwatch();
            SW.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 999; j++)
                {
                    int a = 37;
                    int b = 37;
                    double c = Math.Pow(a, b);
                    string d = "abcde";
                    string e = "abcde";
                    string f = d + e;
                }


            }
            Console.WriteLine(SW.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            SW.Stop();
            Console.ReadKey();
```

in this link Difference Between Data Type in C# and Data Type in .NET[^] "said all data types are converted into .Net Data type"What does this mean?I think if this word is true so converting C# alias data types to .net data types it takes time and i tested this by above codes but i am not sure if anyone sure(***not unsure I emphasize***) please answer me **somebody answer there is no deference in performance but i think this is not my answer** thanks a lot

Comment: Keywords like `int`, `string`, `double` are compiled to their .NET types `System.Int32`, `System.String`, and `System.Double`. There should be no difference.

Comment: I recommend staying away from the aliases anyway. There's nothing stopping someone creating a class called `String` that can suddenly cause your app to behave really strangely.

Comment: @DavidG: That's a reason *to* use the alias `string` when you mean to use `global::System.String`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry yes, I was typing quickly - trying to get out of the door and get my dinner!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [which one is faster data types in .net or data types in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096055/which-one-is-faster-data-types-in-net-or-data-types-in-c).  You are unlikely to get a different answer than last time

Answer (score 3):

> I think if this word is true so converting C# alias data types to .net data types it takes time

No, the aliases are understood at *compile-time*. There is no difference at all in the IL involved, so there is no difference in speed, memory, or anything else.

In terms of *compilation* time, I'd actually expect the use of the aliases (`int` etc) to be infinitessimally faster than using the regular type names (`Int32` etc), as the compiler doesn't need to resolve the name against the namespaces that are imported. But I'd be surprised if the difference was even measurable without deliberately setting up a situation to be very extreme (e.g. by adding thousands of `using` directives, just for the sake of trying to slow the compiler down).

Use whichever form you and your team find most readable. My preference - and the preference of almost every developer I've worked with - is to use the aliases.